# Efficiently shorten a list till first and last appearance of a value different from None

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have lists of the style:

```
[None, ..., None, "c", 1, 3, None, None, 4.3, "b", None, "4", None, ..., None]
```

that I would like to efficiently shorten to:

```
["c", 1, 3, None, None, 4.3, "b", None, "4"]
```

Straight forward I could do:

```
def _shorten(long_list):
  start = False
  short_list = []
  for e in long_list:
    if e:
      start = True
    if start:
      short_list.append(e)
  return short_list

reversed(_shorten(reversed(_shorten(long_list))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
lst = [None, None, None, None]

i = 0
while i < len(lst) - 1 and lst[i] is None:
    i += 1

j = len(lst) - 1
while j > 0 and lst[j] is None:
    j -= 1

print(lst[i : j + 1])
```

---

<sup>EDIT: Removed the first O(n^2) answer</sup>

Comment: It's very inefficient (O n^2) to copy entire list for each and every removal. Better to find the start/end indices and then slice once.

Comment: @wim Updated with more efficient answer.

Comment: Looks better, just one small issue - crashes on a list of all Nones (instead of returning an empty list)

Comment: @wim Good catch :)

Comment: @AndrejKesely hey thanks, that case is for my question irrelevant - will also not be treated in my example - my example does not crash but also wouldn't shorten the list to an empty list - still it can be ignored :)